# Number of rewards before death

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

I have a question regarding Poisson events with death.

Assume time is continuous $t\in[0,\infty)$. A person may die with intensity $\delta$. Conditional on being alive, he may achieve a reward with an independent Poisson process with intensity $\eta$.

Here are my questions and my preliminary thoughts.

1. What's the probability of get AT LEAST $n$ rewards before death? I thought it should be 
   $$
   (\frac{\eta}{\eta+\delta})^n
   $$
   since \frac{\eta}{\eta+\delta} is the probability of get one reward before death. And Poisson process's memory-less feature leads to my conclusion. But not sure whether it is correct.
2. Second, during a period of time $T$, what's his probability of getting EXACTLY $n$ rewards?
   Should be 
   $$
   e^{-\delta T} \frac{e^{-\eta T} (\eta T)^n}{n!}
   $$
   Correct? But I am confused about can I use a coherent approach to get the solutions for question 1 and 2?
3. Assume he dies either due to a $\delta$ event or achieve $N$ rewards. Then given he is alive, what's the probability distribution of number of rewards $n \in\{ 0,1,2,3...N-1\}$ he has achieved?

Please let me know if there is anything unclear or wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: There is one major thing that is unclear: what have you tried?

Comment: @ jameselmore Thanks for the suggestion. I add what I have done.

Comment: From your attempts in $1$ and $2$, it seems that in $1$ you mean "at least $n$ rewards" whereas in $2$ you mean "exactly $n$ rewards"? (Generally speaking, it's usually a good idea to distinguish those two meanings explicitly.)

Comment: @joriki Thanks. Already updated.

Comment: I think Q1 is correct. Q2 is also correct assuming we only want the case where he gets $N$ rewards by time $T$ and doesn't die by time $T$, not the case where he gets $N$ rewards by some time $U\lt T$ and dies at time $U$. Q3 : can you explain further? Either dying or getting $N$ rewards ends the process, right? It makes more sense to count the number of rewards (at end of process) given that he's dead, not given that he's alive.